# How can I deny all IPv6 ssh connection

Tags: networking, security, tcp-wrappers

I want to disable all ssh connection from both IPv4 and IPv6 except certain IPs.

I can set `/etc/hosts.deny` to deny all IPv4 ssh connection:

```
sshd: ALL
```

How to apply to IPv6?

I tried below, and fail:

```
sshd: [*]
```

and

```
sshd: [ALL]
```

My sshd server version: PKIX-SSH 12.1, OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016

And PKIX is configured with `--with-tcp-wrappers`

Comment: You can do it in the local firewall.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, can you tell me more information? I don't understand.

Comment: I have also done it with `ufw` or `gufw` (the graphical front end of `ufw`).  For me I tell it to block everything, except `ssh`, from IP-address xxx. But you can tell it to block everything. What OS are you on?

Comment: I need to apply this setting to embedded system which doesn't have `ufw` to use

Comment: What is the OS and kernel?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "block" all IPv6 connections to your device you can simply not listen on IPv6.

So you can configure sshd_config to listen only on IPv4.
`ListenAddress IPv4:Por`t, example: `ListenAddress 192.168.2.1:22`

or

Define a IPv4 only hostname for your hosts

```
/etc/hosts
192.168.2.1 myhost
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
ListenAddress myhost:22
```

Comment: What I want to do is to disable all IPv6, but I want to let user to add white list.

Comment: that does not make sense. If you want to disable IPv6 across the system then edit the question accordingly. I do not understand what you mean by "let user to add to white list". Once ipv6 is disbale system wide, you cannot use IPv6 any longer. This is valid for both incoming and outgoing connections.